# Having issues in DevOps pipeline creating Firewall rule

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

In the process of using the MS script for creating Firewall rules and having an issue with the parameters, seems the name of the function changed from `New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule` to `New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule`, also I noticed that in some documentation it mentions parameter order which I've now updated but still getting an error:

```
function New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule {
  $agentIP = (New-Object net.webclient).downloadstring("https://api.ipify.org")
  New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ServerName $ServerName -FirewallRuleName $AzureFirewallName -StartIPAddress $agentIp -EndIPAddress $agentIp
}
```

Error is ##[error]A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'ResourceGroupName'

Oddly when i change the order of the params it then moans about FirewallRuleName

Bit of a loss now.

Comment: This example doesn't use the `ResourceGroupName` parameter at all. What happens if you remove it? https://agileramblings.com/2015/07/26/using-powershell-to-set-your-azure-sql-firewall-rule/

Comment: If i remove it switches to another param ##[error]A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'FirewallRuleName'

Comment: again, in the link, there is no `FirewallRuleName` parameter but there is one called `RuleName`. I suggest you use `Get-Help` to understand valid parameters

Comment: Whats really interesting is the func they're calling has now been replaced New-AzureSqlDatabaseServerFirewallRule with New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule

Comment: Things change quickly in the cloud. You just have to adapt

Comment: If you want to use `New-AzSqlServerFirewallRule`, which you should if it's newer, I suggest you use `Get-Help` on that one to get correct parameters

Comment: Going by the doco they certainly appear to be valid parameters. Sorry I've gone around in a circle on this

Comment: and your syntax looks exactly like the example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/new-azsqlserverfirewallrule?view=azps-6.2.1#example-1--create-a-firewall-rule

Answer (score 0):

So after a number of failed attempts finally tripped on the solution the task in the build pipe was running with  task: AzurePowerShell@2 and needs to be  task: AzurePowerShell@5, the documentation on MS isn't correct. PHEW!